# Calling .removeUser() failed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

When i try to put remove user on the password and email it gives me this error :

```
Error: Firebase.removeUser failed: First argument must contain the key "email" with type "string"
    at Error (native)
    at bg (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:134:225)
    at U.Se (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js:258:380)
    at Scope.$scope.removeUser (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/fourm/settingsController.js:8:24)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js:13036:15), <anonymous>:4:221)
    at callback (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js:23090:17)
    at Scope.$eval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js:15719:28)
    at Scope.$apply (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js:15818:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js:23095:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/fourm/jquery.js:4435:9)
```

I dont understand that. I tried several ways of attacking that problem but it didnt work. Help would be very much appreciated, Thankyou [Here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/fourm#openfile-README.md) is my cloud9 file.

And here is the js where it dosent work:

```
 angular.module('LoginApp')
 .controller("settingsController", ["$scope", "AuthService","$firebaseAuth",
        function($scope, AuthService, $firebaseAuth) {

            $scope.removeUser = function(){
                var firebase = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");

              firebase.removeUser({
              email: AuthService.User.email,
              password: AuthService.User.password
            }, function(error) {
              if (error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                  case "INVALID_USER":
                    console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                    break;
                  case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                    console.log("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
                    break;
                  default:
                    console.log("Error removing user:", error);
                }
              } else {
                //Remove Data from our personal data we created    
               firebase.child("users").child(AuthService.User.uid).remove().then(function(){
                   window.location.hash = "/"
                   setTimeout(function(){
                        alert("Successfully Removed")
                   }, 700)
               })
              }
            }); 







            }

            $scope.resetPassword = function(){
                var firebase = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
               firebase.resetPassword({
                  email: AuthService.User.email
                }, function(error) {
                  if (error) {
                    switch (error.code) {
                      case "INVALID_USER":
                        console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                        break;
                      default:
                        console.log("Error resetting password:", error);
                    }
                  } else {
                    console.log("Password reset email sent successfully!");
                  }
                });

            }


        }]
        )
```

Comment: It looks like `AuthService.User.email` is not a string. Since the code for that is not in the question, there's not a lot more I can say about it. It might be good if you create a [minimal, complete verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) inside your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i checked your code in cloud9 and it looks like you forgot to add data to User.email and to User.password in loginController

```
firebase.child("users").child(userData.uid).once('value', function(snapshot){
              AuthService.User.username = snapshot.val().username;
              AuthService.User.uid = userData.uid;
            });
```